В gnome некорректно отображаются иконки
Использую archlinux, gnome. Вместо иконок стоит одна и та же. Пробовал менять тему, не помогло.


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

не установлен стандартный иконпак от гнома
поставь hicolor-icon-theme и adwaita-icon-theme
